# Algorithm to compute edit set for transforming one string into another?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'd like to compute the edits required to transform one string, A, into another string B using only inserts and deletions, with the minimum number of operations required.

So something like "kitten" -> "sitting" would yield a list of operations something like ("delete at 0", "insert 's' at 0", "delete at 4", "insert 'i' at 3", "insert 'g' at 6")

Is there an algorithm to do this, note that I *don't* want the edit distance, I want the actual edits.

Comment: Why the votes to close?  I haven't been able to find this algorithm anywhere.  Everything that's returned by Google refers to Levenshtein/edit distance algorithms.

Comment: That seems a very specific use case. I wouldn't imagine there is an algorithm like that. Why not just for look through each character in the string

Comment: I'd imagine there's a lot of use cases, because you could use the algorithm to transform _any_ list into another with minimum effort as long as you had equality for the elements.

Comment: This link can help: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transform-one-string-to-another-using-minimum-number-of-given-operation/

Comment: This is always going to be O(n), because at a minimum you need to scan each character of each string once just to know what those strings contain.  So if you are already O(n), why not just go with the most simple approach and iterate one character at a time through both strings, and edit the target string to match the input string?

Comment: It's actually quite trivial to modify the minimum edit distance to compute the actual edits not considering substitutions, as long as you understood dynamic programming

Answer (score 1):

I had an assignment similar to this at one point. Try using an A* variant. Construct a graph of possible 'neighbors' for a given word and search outward using A* with the distance heuristic being the number of letter needed to change in the current word to reach the target. It should be clear as to why this is a good heuristic-it's always going to underestimate accurately. You could think of a neighbor as a word that can be reached from the current word only using one operation. It should be clear that this algorithm will correctly solve your problem optimally with slight modification.

Comment: Yeah graph traversal is what I was thinking, but I'd hoped to avoid it if possible.  There's quite efficient algorithms for computing the distance, but apparently not for actually computing the edits.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have delete and insert operations, this is an instance of the Longest Common Subsequence Problem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Indeed, there is a common subsequence of length `k` in two strings `S` and `T`, `S` of length `n` and `T` of length `m`, if and only only you can transform `S` into `T` with `m+n-2k` insert and delete operations. Think about this as intuition : the order of the letters is preserved both when adding and deleting letters, as well as when taking a subsequence.

EDIT : since you asked for the list of edits, a possible way to do the edits is to first remove all the characters of `S` not in the common subsequence, and then insert all the characters of `T` that are not the in common subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make something that works, at least for your precise case.

```
word_before = "kitten"
word_after = "sitting"

# If the strings aren't the same length, we stuff the smallest one with spaces
if len(word_before) > len(word_after):
    word_after += " "*(len(word_before)-len(word_after))
elif len(word_before) < len(word_after):
    word_before += " "*(len(word_after)-len(word_before))

operations = []

for idx, char in enumerate(word_before):
    if char != word_after[idx]:
        if char != " ":
            operations += ["delete at "+str(idx)]
        operations += ["insert '"+word_after[idx]+"' at "+str(idx)]

print(operations)
```

Comment: `"string"` to `"sting"` would only need to remove the `r`.  your algorithm instead replacing it with i, then replacing the next i with n, then replacing the next n with g... seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for, using `itertools.zip_longest` to zip the lists together and iterate over them in pairs compares them and applies the correct operation, it appends the operation to a list at the end of each operation, it compares the lists if they match and breaks out or continues if they don't

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = "kitten"
b = "sitting"

def transform(a, b):
    ops = []
    for i, j in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=''):
        if i == j:
            pass
        else:
            index = a.index(i)
            print(a, b)
            ops.append('delete {} '.format(i)) if i != '' else ''
            a = a.replace(i, '')
            if a == b:
                break
            ops[-1] += 'insert {} at {},'.format(j, index if i not in b else b.index(j))
    return ops

result = transform(a, b)

print(result, ' {} operation(s) was carried out'.format(len(result)))
```